# Sitecore 8.2 update 1 , publish preview error

Tags: migration, sitecore, sitecore8

[image]When I try to publish-preview an item , I am getting the following error.

Comment: and what is logs?

Comment: 4484 20:57:33 ERROR Failed to render rendering
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/Speak/Ribbon/Controls/LargeButton/LargeButton.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').

Comment: Can be a possible duplicate of the following question: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6201/experience-editor-server-error-8-1/6216#6216

Comment: Hi Hishaam , 
I checked the question you referenced , in that question's screenshot , the page is not getting rendered whereas the page is getting rendered but ribbon is not showing in above question.
Also , this is in Sitecore 8.2 Version 161115 , other question is related with Sitecore 8.1 Version 160519